How to install tensorflow_text? Gives error everytime
Whenever I try to install tensorflow_text on my system, it gives the following error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text==2.16.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text==2.16.1.

I saw the README of tensorflow_text and it was clearly mentioned that the tensorflow_text version should be the same as the tensorflow version installed. I have 2.16.1 therefore I tried to install that and still getting the error.
I tried to install it with the following commands and got the same error message:
pip install tensorflow-text
pip install tensorflow_text==2.16.1
pip install -U tensorflow_text==2.16.1
pip install -U tensorflow-text==2.16.1


After version 2.10, Tensorflow/text only provides pip packages for Linux x86_64 and Intel-based Macs. tensorflow-text 2.16.1 provides wheels for Python 3.9-3.11. What is your OS and Python version?

python version is 3.12 and I am using my University HPC Cluster where I have made the conda environment and installing all the packages

I don't know what that HPC Cluster runs. If it's Linux — that's Ok. But you need Python 3.11. Or you have to compile tensorflow-text from sources but the compilation could fail if the code is not yet adapted to Python 3.12.

I degraded the current python version which was 3.12 to 3.9 and tensorflow_text got installed. My assumption is that it is not compatible with the current version (3.12) of Python.
For installation details visit: https://github.com/tensorflow/text
